# ISupportIncrementalLoading inside ScrollViewer not supported?

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

I have a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) with [GridView.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) set to a collection that implements [ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading.aspx).  By implementing this, I am aiming to improve load time and UI responsiveness by only loading items that are needed for display.  The framework handles this for me and it works great.

```
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

**However**, if I wrap the above XAML in a ScrollViewer like the following, **the entire collection of Items loads** as though the GridView is unable to tell where it's boundaries are.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I know that the ScollViewer will allow it's content to fill as much space as it wants, so the effect here does make sense; it is just an unforeseen annoyance.  Does anyone have a solution to getting around this problem?

*Note: I've simplified the code here for example sake.  In case it helps to know what I'm trying to accomplish: my goal is to have an incrementally loaded GridView inside a HubSection on my Hub page.  My hub page has 2 HubSections, one that is at 600px width and the other with the GridView in it with no width defined.*

Comment: The question is why would you put a `GridView` in a `ScrollViewer` if there is already a `ScrollViewer` in the `GridView`?

Comment: @FilipSkakun I'm actually trying to put the GridView in a HubSection.  The problem presents itself in both scenarios.  I figure that people are probably more familiar with the ScrollViewer control.

Comment: Right, the Hub control also has a ScrollViewer and so the same problem applies. So does my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that easily by setting the size of the `GridView` manually. Depending on your scenario you might do it once or perhaps handle the `SizeChanged` event on the `ScrollViewer` and set the size of the `GridView` based on the viewport size properties of the `ScrollViewer`.